# Rake cucumber in Rails without dropping Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rake

Running Cucumber Test in rails seems to by default drop and recreate Test database.

Was wondering if there is anywhere to not drop and recreate Test database during each test?

Using:
Rails 3.1
cucumber 1.1.o
cucumber-rails 1.1.1

Command used:
Rake cucumber

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cucumber does reset the test database after each scenario.  That's normally what you want, but sometimes you might want some persistent data that never gets reset.  If thats your case, you can modify how database_cleaner works in features/support/env.rb

Look for

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
```

and replace it with your version of

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[directions locations]}
```

Where "directions locations" are the names of the tables you don't want cleared out ever.